# On upgrading from Unity 5.5 to 5.6, there is a significant drop in FPS and the number of batches are reduced in GPU Instancing

Tags: unity-game-engine

FPS is reduced on upgrading my Unity project from 5.5 to 5.6. On investigating the issue, I found that the number of batches(GPU Instancing) in 5.6 is very low when compared with 5.5. I also found the reason for the mesh not being batched in 5.6 frame debugger as "GPU instancing not happening due to different mesh or submesh". Any idea why did that happen only in 5.6?

Comment: Instancing only works for objects that have the same mesh and material. Also, does the material have `Enable Instancing` set?

Comment: Yes. Instancing is enabled and it is happening but not for all the meshes which was instanced in Unity 5.5 @rutter